# How to make a revoluteJoint oscillate?

Tags: android, box2d

I have created a revoluteJoint with a motor and lower & upper limits. I would like to know how to make the revoluteJoint oscillate between the lower & upper limits. Currently the body swings from the lower to the upper limit and then stops. Any help will be appreciated. This is the code

```
   final RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef2 = new RevoluteJointDef();   
   revoluteJointDef2.initialize(legBody, circleBody1, circleBody1.getWorldCenter());
   revoluteJointDef2.enableMotor = true;
   revoluteJointDef2.enableLimit = true;
   rj2 = (RevoluteJoint) this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(revoluteJointDef2);
   rj2.setMotorSpeed(2);
   rj2.setMaxMotorTorque(10);
   rj2.setLimits((float)(30 * (Math.PI)/180), (float)(270 * (Math.PI)/180));
```

How do I make the joint reverse direction and repeat again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create an oscilatting revoluteJoint by implementing a timer task. Every time the timer fires I reverse the motor speed and make the revoluteJoint oscillate between lower & upper limits.

```
    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
       RevoluteJoint rj1;;
        RemindTask(RevoluteJoint rj){
        rj1 = rj;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("x","x" +"Reversing motor");
        reverseMotor();          
    }

    public void reverseMotor(){
        rj1.setMotorSpeed(-(rj1.getMotorSpeed()));
        rj1.setMaxMotorTorque(100);

    }
}
```

For a link to implementation and code please take a look at my blog post http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/simulating-an-oscillating-revolutejoint-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Do at every step:

```
if ((joint->GetUpperLimit() - joint->GetJointAngle()) < yourSomeAlpha)
{
     // Reached upper limit, go to another limit
     joint->SetMotorSpeed(-2);
}
if ((joint->GetJointAngle() - joint->GetLowerLimit()) < yourSomeAlpha)
{
     // Reached lower limit, go to another limit
     joint->SetMotorSpeed(2);
}
```

Parameter `yourSomeAlpha` choose experimental. Try, for example, 0.01.

Comment: Pavel, Thanks for your answer. I am not sure what you mean at every step. When I execute the code it runs through to the upper limit. Also if I check joint->GetUpperLimit it is going to get the predefined upper limit which is 270 in the above code and is not going to return the current angle made by the joint. How can we check that?

Comment: Every time step is mean between any two calls of b2World::Step. In another words, every frame of the game. Current angle of the joint returns GetReferenceAngle, not GetUpperLimit.